# Why database connection object or connection pool needs to be made singleton?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, connection, singleton

I have gone through couple of articles on singleton example. And I could see that developers sometimes make the database connection object or connection manager as singleton implementation. In some of the posts even it was advised to use Database connection pool. 
Well Singleton means to create a single instance, so basically we restrict the access. e.g. Printer or hardware access, logger access in which we try to restrict the access of the user to one at a time using singleton. However what is the purpose of using singleton in DB connection objects?
If I can understand correctly creating a Database connection as singleton means that app server will have only one instance. Does this mean only one user can access the Database connection and next user has to wait until the connection is closed?
Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

I think you understand correctly the implication of making the connection itself a singleton. Generally it is not a good idea (although in some very particular case it could make sense).

Making a connection manager or a connection pool a singleton is completely different. The pool itself would handle a collection of connections and it can create new as they are needed (up to a limit) or re-use the ones that have been already used and discarded.

Having several connection pools at the same time would lose the advantages of the pool:

- It would be harder to control the total number of connections open
- One pool could be creating connections while other could have connections available

Hope this helps to clarify the subject. You might want to read more on connection pools.

Comment: One thing that's worth noting, it's good for connection pools to be a "logical singleton" (i.e. only one instance per DB / user) for exactly the reasons described here. But it's usually a bad idea to actually implement as a singleton (there really can be only one) as it make it hard to mock for things such as unit testing.

Comment: Just to the point answer. Thank you. One more query - What is the benefit of making the connection pool object as singleton? From your description it seems like if we make Connection object as singleton one user can use the connection at a time. So it doesn't seem very beneficial. Possibly this might be used if there are not many user to access the application or may be users are trying to download big file etc. However just wondering what will be the benefit if we make the ConnectionPool as singleton?

Comment: The answer mentions two problems resulting of the possibility of having more than one connection pool. Making it a singleton would avoid those problems.

Answer (score 0):

Q: "However what is the purpose of using singleton in DB connection objects?" 
 A: There is (almost always) none. So your thinking is correct.

Q: "Does this mean only one user can access the Database connection and next user has to wait until the connection is closed?" 
A: Depends (to first part) and No (to second part after "and"). 
In single-threaded application only one user will use the database at one time and another will wait, until dispatch of first user ends but not when the connection is closed. Once connection is closed, you need to create another connection to make use of database. 
In multi-threaded application many threads may be using the same connection instance and result really depends on the vendor implementation: may block dispatching (effectively transforming your app to single-threaded app) or throw exceptions or even something different. However, such design in multi-threaded app is in my opinion a programmer-error.

Comment: Just to the point answer. Thank you. One more query - What is the benefit of making the connection pool object as singleton? From your description it seems like if we make Connection object as singleton one user can use the connection at a time. So it doesn't seem very beneficial. Possibly this might be used if there are not many user to access the application or may be users are trying to download big file etc. However just wondering what will be the benefit if we make the ConnectionPool as singleton?